# How to detect columnar pdf page using pdfBox?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am trying to read text from pdf and create tables from it using `pdfbox` in `java`. I am stuck with [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9q9YK3qNDvxRlBrTEZUT0ZaYWc/view?usp=sharing) pdf. On the first page, you can see that the page is divided into two columns, and the table is on the right side of the page. I use the `processStream` method to get the characters:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<TextPosition>> pageExtractor(PDPage page, String readingType) throws Exception {
    setReadingType(readingType);
    setPageWidth(page.getMediaBox().getWidth());
    setPageHeight(page.getMediaBox().getHeight());
    normalSpacing = this.getSpacingTolerance();
    PDStream contents = page.getContents();
    if (contents != null) {
        //Function to extract the pdf characters and join the words (@Override processTextPosition(TextPosition text) function is called after this function)
        this.processStream(page, page.findResources(), page.getContents().getStream()); //Main Function which loops over all the characters in pdfpage.
        if (!oneLineCharacterList.isEmpty())characterList.add(oneLineCharacterList);
    }
    return characterList;
}
```

The following function is called for each character in PDPage:

```
protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition text) {
    System.out.println(text.getCharacter());
}
```

The order of above function being called depends on the order of writing a pdf. It can be in a haphazard way. If you select all and copy the text of above linked pdf in a text file, that is the order in which `processTextPosition` is called. Thus, you can see that `chart 1` is read after the table on the right is read.

Now, established that the reading order of pdf page is not defined, I want to read the pdf in a definite manner. Had the pdf page not been divided into columns, I could have easily arranged all the words according to coordinates once all the page is read and know the correct order. But, since the above pdf is divided into two columns (one starting with `Latest Week's Sales Snapshot` and other one `ICSC-Goldman Sachs Weekly`), how do I determine that the page is actually columnar? i.e. Arrange the text in such a way that left column text comes first, right column text comes after? Do we have any function inside the [`PDPage`](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.10/javadocs/index.html?org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDPage.html) to determine if the page is divided into columns or not? Another example of two columns pdf in which I want to arrange the first column text first and second column text after that is [this](https://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/AAAI/AAAI12/paper/download/5046/5244) opposed to pdfs without any columnar structure such as [this](http://www.bls.gov/news.release/pdf/empsit.pdf) (page no 2).

**EDIT**

After going through the documentation of [`PDFTextStripper`](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.10/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/util/PDFTextStripper.html#setSortByPosition(boolean)) class, I see the field `charactersByArticle` which might solve my problem. But how do I populate this field (along with others) given the `PDDocument` object already populated for the class? Here is what I tried:

```
package com.pdfExtractor.extractArticles;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.CryptographyException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper;

public class ArticleExtractor extends PDFTextStripper{

    List<PDPage> pages;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ArticleExtractor(PDDocument document) throws IOException {
        super();
        super.setSortByPosition(true);      
        this.document = document;
        pages = new ArrayList<PDPage>(this.document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages());
    }


    public void extractArticles(int pageNumber) throws IOException {
        //Some code to process the document, so that the variables below are populated
        this.processStream(this.pages.get(pageNumber), this.pages.get(pageNumber).getResources(), this.pages.get(pageNumber).getContents().getStream());
        System.out.println(this.getFonts());
        this.startDocument(this.document);
        System.out.println(this.charactersByArticle);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, CryptographyException {
        PDDocument document= null;
        File input = new File("C:\\Users\\prabhjot.rai\\Desktop\\xceligent\\11365798.pdf");
        document = PDDocument.load(input);
        if (document.isEncrypted()) {
            document.decrypt("");
        }        
        document.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
        ArticleExtractor articleExtractor = new ArticleExtractor(document);
        articleExtractor.extractArticles(1);
    }

}
```

And it gives me empty arrays as output on the console. What logic do I need to implement to populate those fields?

Comment: are you aware of `setSortByPosition()` ?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Yes. I have already set it true in my class implementation of `PDFTextStripper`

Comment: `charactersByArticle` requires the PDF in question to have a special list describing the column structure. Most likely your PDF does not have such a list and, therefore, finds no information based on article.

Comment: @mkl when does the `this.charactersByArticle` get populated(if any)? Is it when I call the `this.processStream` method? Or is it when I assign document to `this.document` in the constructor?

Comment: @mkl moreover, in the documentation I found a line in the definition of `charactersByArticle` that says `Most PDFs won't have any beads, so charactersByArticle will contain a single entry`. Thus, I should not get an empty array but atleast one entry. How to populate `charactersByArticle`?

Comment: First of all, I just checked your three sample documents. None of them contains article thread or article bead objects (which form the list I mentioned before). Thus, the article support of PDFBox won't help you for them.

Comment: Then `charactersByArticle` is initialized and the page is parsed during `processPage` which usually is called during `processPages` which in turn  is called by `writeText` which eventually is called by `getText`. As you do not call `processPage`, your `charactersByArticle` never is properly initialized.

Comment: So, you mean if I write `this.getText(this.document)` in my constructor of `class ArticleExtractor`, the `charactersByArticle` will be populated?

Comment: *"So, you mean..."* - I mean you should not skip the initialization steps done in `processPage` in particular. Whether you necessarily have to call `getText` or whether it is more apropos to copy the initialization code itself, depends very much on your use case and your PDFBox proficiency.